# Incorrect syntax near ')' in SQL

Tags: sql, subquery

I am a newbie in SQL and I do not know what is wrong with this code :

```
select 
    t.title, pub.pub_name 
from 
    titles t 
inner join 
    publishers pub on t.title_id = pub.pub_id
where 
    t.title_id in (select title_id 
                   from
                       (select t.title_id, sum(s.qty) 
                        from titles t 
                        inner join sales s on t.title_id = s.title_id
                        group by t.title_id
                        having sum(s.qty) > 20)
                  )
```

Do you folks know why this is not working?

Comment: What RDBMS do you use? SQL Server?

Comment: From what I can see  your sub query should have an alias too.

Comment: use alias in sub-query :  select t.title_id from(..... )... ;

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are using SQL Server, and your error is because you don't use alias for your table in subquery. You could fix it by name an alias for it.

But IMO you should rewrite your query to this simple version:

```
SELECT t.title , pub.pub_name 
FROM titles t 
INNER JOIN publishers pub 
ON t.title_id = pub.pub_id
WHERE t.title_id IN (
    SELECT title_id 
    FROM titles t 
    INNER JOIN sales s 
    ON t.title_id = s.title_id
    GROUP BY t.title_id
    HAVING SUM(s.qty) > 20
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add alias to your Sub Query

```
select
  t.title,
  pub.pub_name
from
  titles t
  inner join publishers pub on t.title_id = pub.pub_id
where
  t.title_id in (
    select
      title_id
    from(
        select
          t.title_id,
          sum(s.qty)
        from
          titles t
          inner join sales s on t.title_id = s.title_id
        group by
          t.title_id
        having
          sum(s.qty) > 20
      ) as t_id
  )
```

Or else it will throw an error at ) with something like this

> Every derived table must have its own alias

A good way to test your queries is to use validators online

http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: should't we should use alias here also ??  where

    select
      title_id
    from(...)...

Comment: it is throw an error `No column name was specified for column 2 of 't_id'.
`

Comment: My bad, you should change the name of the alias to specify the column you want to get. I did not see you have two columns to fect in your sub query.